# Topic side compression in apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

If we do not mention the compression type on kafka producer, and if we mention it on the broker side... How is the performance impacted and in what batch sizes does topic side compression work on?

Answer (score 1):

Compression will work only if you specify on the producer side, otherwise data will be stored in uncompressed format on the disk. 
Compression increases the I/O throughput for some compression and decompression cost on the client side. Also, it saves disk space as data will be stored in the compressed format in the kafka brokers.
You can keep the batch size up to the maximum message size allowable limit by the kafka broker, that is 1 MB

Comment: So do u mean that compression is not possible on the topic side... And if we compress the messages on producer side in batches... How will checkpointing work in case of a hardware failure?

Comment: Yes..compression is always determined by producer. A topic can have combination of compressed and uncompressed messages. On the client side (consumer), the messages are again uncompressed and given to the consumer application. Checkpointing is done by the kafka consumer. I did not get your second part of the question clearly.